# How can I get CodeBlocks to compile with -std=c++0x with gcc?

Tags: c++11, codeblocks

How can I get CodeBlocks to compile with -std=c++0x with gcc?

I would like to see if they treat new features with useful syntax highlighting.  Also, I have a lot of stuff n C++-0x now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy: Put `-std=c++0x -U__STRICT_ANSI__` or `-std=gnu++0x -U__STRICT_ANSI__` (if you want GNU extensions too) into either your project's build options (compiler, other options), or set them in the *global* compiler options (settings menu).

You need to undef `__STRICT_ANSI__` or you get trouble with some legacy headers (I believe it's mostly `stdio`) that are inevitably sometimes included from some 3rd party code.

Comment: The extra bit about the global options gets the checkmark.  OTOH I probably wont use it because I still use old C++ sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Look in Project's "Build" properties, you'll see configurations tab for the compiler. Then select all the configurations, go in the list of features and select "C++0x".

My current CodeBlocks (last public release) don't recognize C++0x keyword at all. Not even auto.

Comment: I've got 10.05 (Ubuntu standard package) and it seems to highlight auto.  I'm not getting decltype highlighted.

Comment: Actually, auto was a keyword (with different semantics **before** C++-0x so it really doesn't count.

Comment: Yes and what I meant was that it should detect auto and give the inferred type in tooltips, but it doesn't and it also breaks using Ctrl+Space with any type declared as auto.

Comment: Support for C++0x keyword highlighting was added in late 2008, but it somehow mysteriously disappeared. With rev 7263 (available with the next nightly builds), C++0x keywords including most of the standard library (excluding some painfully "noisy" parts like `regex` and `random`) have been re-added.