# The auto type specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I just learnt about the auto type specifiers, and tried to use it in a very simple code

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
 using namespace std;
int a = 21;
auto c = a;
cout<<c;
}
```

On running, this code gives an error that says 'warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Compile with C++11.

Comment: Which compiler and command-line options are you using? Some compilers don't support C++11, for some you need to enable it. E.g. for gcc, pass `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x` when using 4.6.x).

Comment: I'm using codeblocks.
What do you recommend I use?

Comment: I don't about C++11 but..... `isn't auto a storage specifier`....? `do we not need to add type after auto like auto int c?`

Comment: If you do "stackoverflow C++ activate C++11 compiler" o Google, you'll get existing questions covering the details for various compilers.

Comment: Is there a way I can enable c++11 in codeblocks itself? I'm really comfortable with codeblocks, and would prefer to stick to it.

Comment: so auto specifier automatically gets type by the assignment type?

Comment: @judas Does this answer the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528595/how-can-i-get-codeblocks-to-compile-with-std-c0x-with-gcc

Comment: @pinkpanther, I don't think so. That's the whole point of the auto type specifier.

Comment: @pinkpanther In C++03 and earlier you are right. In C++11 no longer.

Comment: @jogojapan is it true in C11 also?

Comment: @judas, In the compiler options of 10.05, there's a `-std=c++0x` option and you can add `-std=c++11` in the next tab. In 12.11, `-std=c++11` is a checkbox as well. I believe 12.11 comes with 4.7.1 as well (and 10.05 is something like 4.4.1), though I'd recommend upgrading to 4.8 :)

Comment: Thank you! The link Jogojapan posted was helpful. Thank you Chris and the rest!

Comment: @pinkpanther I am much less familiar with the C Standards, but I believe C11 did not introduce type deduction through `auto`.

Comment: @jogojapan, I just looked. It's still a storage class specifier in C11.

Comment: @chris Ah, good to be sure. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Code::Blocks, you need to go into the program settings, find compiler options and check the box that says -std=c++0x by it.

By default, it compiles in C++03 mode, where `auto` means something different, so it gives you the warning you say. In order to enable (partial) C++11 support including `auto`, you need to pass the appropriate option to the compiler. In the case of Code::Blocks, it has a menu with checkboxes listing common compiler settings.