# NDK compilation error: 'stod' was not declared in this scope

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I know there is a possible dup here:
[error: 'stod' was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437984/error-stod-was-not-declared-in-this-scope) but I already tried what advised there.
I try to compile a C++ application in Android NDK.

I get error:

> 'stod' was not declared in this scope

I enabled C++ 11 in `Application.mk`:

```
APP_ABI := x86 
APP_STL := gnustl_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION:= 4.8
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -std=c++11 -fpermissive -frtti  -pthread
```

What else should I do in order to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you probably figured out that this isn't part of the current Android NDK (10).  There are several missing pieces from the C++11 libraries, such as regex functionality and to_string, etc.